# PowerMockito.mockStatic() but still getting NPE when static method is called

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, option-type, powermockito

NOTE - I've marked 3 `LINE` numbers which I discuss in my question, you may need to scroll to the right in the code snippets to see.

I'm really struggling unit testing a method with chained `Optional.map()`s.

```
@Override
public void accept(Object message)
{
    extractSenderReference(message.toString())
        .map(t ->
        {
            t.setTransactionStatus("TAG1"); //  <- LINE #1
            return t;
        })
        .map(StaticConverter::convert) //< -LINE #2
        .ifPresent(Persist::persist);
}
```

Where `extractSenderReference()` returns an `Optional` of type `Obj` and is a private method.

And my test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ClassBeingTested.class, StaticConverter.class})

public class MyTest {

private ClassBeingTested updateProcessor = PowerMockito.spy(new ClassBeingTested());
private StatusDataObj statusDataObj = mock(StatusDataObj.class);

@Test
public void testSomething() throws Exception{
    Obj myObj = getObj();
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticConverter.class);

    PowerMockito.doReturn(Optional.ofNullable(myObj)).when(updateProcessor, "extractSenderReference", anyString()); // <- LINE #3
    when(StaticConverter.convert(myObj)).thenReturn(statusDataObj);
    updateProcessor.accept("MESSAGE1");
}

private Obj getObj(){
    Obj obj = new Obj();
    obj.setId(100L);
    return obj;
 }
}
```

At `LINE #1`, as marked in my `accept()` method, object `t` has been processed and has had its `transactionStatus` set successfully.  However at `LINE #2` I am getting a NPE when running the above test.

I've also tried `PowerMockito.spy(StaticConverter.class);` instead of `PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticConverter.class);` as per https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#mocking-static-method but I'm getting the same NPE.

My thinking was map is converting `t` to `StatusDataObj` type.  So when map calls `convert`, I'll stub and return my type.  However, originally I was expecting that `LINE #3` would effectively take care of the chained `map` calls on the `Optional` returned from `extractSenderReference()`, since I'm using a real object with values set, but there must be a null value somewhere else?

Comment: Could your code by any chance be presented as [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? When I try to read through it, I feel there are quite many unknowns.

Comment: Does `Obj` implement `equals` (and `hashCode`) correctly? If not, I suspect it might stand a better chance of working if you store `getObj()` in a variable, and use it in both places.

Comment: @AndyTurner good shout but unfortunately the same outcome.  I've updated the snippets to reflect the change.

Comment: @OleV.V. I've removed some method calls and replaced with return types to simplify.

Comment: Can you show how you annotated the Test Class?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Updated.  I have included `@PrepareForTest({ClassBeingTested.class, StaticConverter.class})` in my code, if this is what you're after :)

Comment: Try replacing the method reference `StaticConverter::convert` with an explicit lambda call to the actual method: `e -> StaticConverter.convert(e)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Persist` was null.  I'm not sure why the NPE was at `LINE 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the method reference `StaticConverter::convert` with an explicit lambda call to the actual method: `e -> StaticConverter.convert(e)`.

I've had issues with Powermock mocking method references, but by leaving it as an explicit method call I could successfully mock those calls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the classes to the `@PrepareForTest` with which you will be working in that test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticConverter.class, ClassBeingTested.class)
```

Powermock needs to be aware you will be using it for these classes.

Comment: These are included, I've updated my code example.  Getting same `NPE`

Comment: are you sure the first map does not transform to an Optional? Also ifPresent is part of an Optional inerface, not Stream. Also that stream has no terminal operation, how does that even compile /run?

Comment: The first map does transform to an `Optional`.

Comment: is StaticConverter.convert overloaded?

Comment: Nope, there's only one method in the `StaticConverter` class, and it's called `convert`.